# How Estimate Capacity for a Battery If the Temperature is Changing Constantly

Tags: batteries, efficiency

It is the first time I am trying to estimate a battery capacity to can use some devices autonomously.

I found this equation:

`Hours autonomy = Battery Capacity x Voltage x Unit x Battery Efficiency / load`

`for example = 100Ah x 24 V x 1 x 0.8/ 150 W = 12,8 h`

But reading from [here](https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/discharging_at_high_and_low_temperatures) I saw than the efficiency or capacity of the battery change according to the operation environment temperature.

So, If I will use the battery in a environment where the environment temperature changes a lot until -20 Celsius

How to calculate the correct battery for a load 90W (for example) :

- the formule is not valid ?
- I need to use integral or complex equations?
- I need to do a model of the behavior of the battery in the real place, then make another complex analysis ?
- Can I use the worst case of efficiency of battery to use the formule ?

Answer (score 1):

The formula assumes that the temperature is constant. If the battery will be subject to temperature changes that you cannot control, then the safest approach is to assume the worst case temperature (and the corresponding battery capacity) for the whole period. If you have some control and can predict a temperature profile, then you can use that profile to calculate an average battery capacity based on the temperature and the time at that temperature (this can be done piecewise if the profile is not too complicated but you could use an integral if you need more accuracy). By the way, do you know that the current draw of your device remains constant with temperature? If not, you should also take this into account.

Comment: Hello thanks for your help. I don't understand this part of your answer <<the corresponding battery capacity>>. And the idea is achieve autonomy of 1 hour for a network device, so I am assuming a watt value of the datasheet constantly. I know is not correct, but I don't how solve this problem very well. The battery will be also charging while the vehicule dont use the circuit of autonomy.

Comment: In your question, you say that the capacity of the battery changes with the temperature. I am simply saying that if you know the temperature, use the battery capacity at that temperature when calculating operating time.